# Which one is correct? I am *even more happy* for you! or *even happier*?

Tags: american-english

Which one is correct?
Even more happy or even happier?

P.S.: My question has more to do with the combination of the word "happy" with the word "even", on the context above.

Comment: They're both fine.

Comment: Note that *I am most happy to hear that* is still fairly common (albeit a bit formal / dated, and quite strongly associated with non-mainstream "Indian English" today), but *I am **happiest** to hear that* isn't at all idiomatic. In such contexts, ***most*** actually means ***very*** - it's not really a "superlative" drawing a comparison against (my) other "states of happiness".